How to calculate predicted probabilites for MNL models estimated with mlogit() in R?
I have estimated a Multinomial Logit (MNL) Model using mlogit() from the R package mlogit:
df_long<- mlogit::mlogit.data(data = df_wide, choice = "vote", shape = "wide")
mnl_model <- mlogit::mlogit(vote ~ 1 | var1 + var2 + var3,
                            data = df_long, reflevel = "A")

How can I calculate the predicted probabilities of choosing "A" for different levels of var1 (=values between 1 and 10), using a specific value for var2 and the mean of var3?
Is there a way to do this with marginaleffects::predictions()?
Basically I want to reproduce in R what the following Stata command would do:
mlogit vote var1 i.var2 var3
margins, at(var1=(1(1)10) var2=1 (mean) var3) predict(outcome(1))

There are six different alternatives in the dataset (factor variable with 1 = "A", 2 = "B", ...)
If it's too complicated, it would be already a great help if there was a possibility to reproduce only margins, at(var1=(1(1)10)) in R and ignore the other variables (in the best case with functions in the marginaleffects package, but this is not mandatory).
I tried the following to at least get the predicted probabilites of the different values of var1 (ignoring the other variables):
marginaleffects::predictions(
  mnl_model ,
  newdata = datagrid(var1 = (1:10)),
  type = "response")

But then I get the following error:

The newdata argument for mlogit models must be a data frame with a number of rows equal to a multiple of the number of choices: 6.


The error you are getting is because datagrid() returns one row per value of var1, but mlogit expects one row per combination of var1 and vote. Here is a detailed vignette on mlogit + marginaleffects: https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/categorical.html#mlogit-package

Note that there is a minor bug in version 0.20.1 of marginaleffects which affects mlogit processing. You may want to install the development version from Github: remotes::install_github("vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects")

@Vincent Thanks. The vignette talks about slopes (using avg_slopes). But what I need are predictions. I tried to use the TravelMode example from the vignette with marginaleffects::predictions(). But that doesn't really work (code: predictions(mod, newdata = nd, variables = c("income", "size"))). For example it never shows predictions for size = 3, 4 or 5.
Am I making a mistake or is there a problem with predictions() ?
